# What are good benchmarking programs for measuring usb stick performances?

Tags: windows-xp, benchmarking

*Title pretty much says it all ... anyone know of a benchmarking program for measuring usb sticks read/write speeds ? (if it can produce its own files, even better ... in terms of (lots of small files)/(few big ones)).*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a few that I've used and find quite good:

- [ATTO Dsik Benchmark](http://www.attotech.com/products/product.php?sku=Disk_Benchmark)
- [CrystalDiskMark](http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskMark/index-e.html)
- [HD Tach](http://www.simplisoftware.com/Public/index.php?request=HdTach)

They all use their own files, with different sizes; they're quite comprehensive. If you like any of them, let me know.

Comment: That second one will suit me nicely, thanks! (apart from their Mb/s quircks, but I'm only interested in relative speed - one to another - not absolute).

Comment: @Idigas Check out Sisoft Sandra, I think it provides a relative comparison

Comment: @Sathya - thanks. I will. (remember Sandra from a while ago ... for some reason I stopped using it at some point in time ... ?)

Comment: To get CrystalDiskMark without adware, instructions from [http://download.cnet.com/CrystalDiskMark/9241-2094_4-13062704.html?messageID=10923579&tag=uo;uo](andrewbaggins on CNET): 
`To get CrystalDiskMark without the add-on "Open Candy" ad-ware go to this link: http://crystalmark.info/download/index-e.html Scroll down to CrystalDiskMark and select the "Portable (zip)" version to download. Then right-click the downloaded file and choose "Extract all". The un-zipped folder contains regular and 64-bit versions. Double-click on the one you want to run. No adware or spyware in that version.`

Answer (score 1):

Try [UserBenchMark](http://usb.userbenchmark.com/Software), it has a web interface that allows you to compare results for your device with other users.

- Drive benchmarks include: read, write and mixed IO.
- Checks include: 4k Align, NCQ, TRIM, SATA, USB & S.M.A.R.T.