# Hard Drive benchmark for RAID-0

Tags: software-rec, raid, benchmarking

My buddy uses Crystal Disk to run a benchmark on his SSD hard drive.  I have a 2-Drive Raid-O setup and I want to see how it performs against his SSD, but when I open the program it seems as though it doesn't support RAID.

What is the best (free) program to benchmark my hard drive?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are good benchmarking programs for measuring usb stick performances ?](http://superuser.com/questions/145928/what-are-good-benchmarking-programs-for-measuring-usb-stick-performances)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crystal Disk did the trick!  http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/manual-en/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Passmark Performance Test](http://www.passmark.com/products/pt.htm).

Answer (score 0):

What operating system?

There is [iozone](http://www.iozone.org/) that can be installed from synaptic in ubuntu. There is also a windows port with cygwin