# How do I test USB drive speed?

Tags: windows, speed, usb-flash-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are good benchmarking programs for measuring usb stick performances ?](https://superuser.com/questions/145928/what-are-good-benchmarking-programs-for-measuring-usb-stick-performances)

What are the best (free) tools to test the speed of my USB drives? Reading, writing, general characteristics, I'm sure there is quite something to it. Where do I start?

Edit: I mean for Windows.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[IOMeter](http://www.iometer.org/) is the most useful storage performance testing program I've seen for windows systems. It's not "point-and-click" simple, but fairly easy to grasp and fairly flexible as well.

Answer (score 1):

On Unix, you can use the command dd like so:

```
time dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/usbdrive/zerofile bs=1024 count=1024
```

This will write to a file of 1M zeros to the device then return a message telling you the write transfer rate.
Switch the terms for if and of to get the read transfer rate.
Use varying values for count as desired.

Answer (score 1):

You should try [HD Speed](http://www.steelbytes.com/?mid=20). It's pretty light. ALternatively, you could just copy a large file to and from your USB key and measure how long it takes. Windows Vista and 7 will even tell you how fast its going.